# Calculate Number of Consecutive Days Where a Condition Applies Across Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to below:

```
+-------------------------+
¦ ID ¦ Date     ¦ Balance ¦
¦----+----------+---------¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200620 ¦ 150     ¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200621 ¦ -130    ¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200621 ¦ -140    ¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200621 ¦ -200    ¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200622 ¦ 200     ¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200622 ¦ 300     ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200621 ¦ 350     ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200621 ¦ 400     ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200621 ¦ -150    ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200622 ¦ -200    ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200622 ¦ -300    ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200623 ¦ -400    ¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200623 ¦ -500    ¦
+-------------------------+
```

I need to calculate the number of consecutive days where "Balance <0" for reach ID and for each distinct Date (including the date itself in the calculation). Each Id might have several balances in a given date either positive amount or negative. Even if one balance amount in a given day is negative, the query should take that day into account. The output result should be similar to the table below:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
¦ ID ¦ Date     ¦ Number_of_Consecutive_Days ¦
¦----+----------+----------------------------¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200620 ¦ Null                       ¦
¦----+----------+----------------------------¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200621 ¦ 1                          ¦
¦----+----------+----------------------------¦
¦ A  ¦ 20200622 ¦ 1                          ¦
¦----+----------+----------------------------¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200621 ¦ Null                       ¦
¦----+----------+----------------------------¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200622 ¦ 2                          ¦
¦----+----------+----------------------------¦
¦ B  ¦ 20200623 ¦ 3                          ¦
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Could you please suggest me a way to calculate that? It is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the value on the third row.  What happens if there is a positive day between negative days?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use zero instead of null?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, Thanks for your response. If there is a positive day while we have a negative balance at the same day, the query should count that day. As long as we have at least one negative balance in a given date, we count it.

Comment: Hi @shawnt00, to me it makes more sense to be Null as zero means there is no date provided that criteria, but do you think it can make it easier having zero instead of null?

Comment: Yes, I think I would argue for a zero. It still tells you how many dates matched the criteria.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry, This table does not include a primary key. Does that affect the solution?

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY then you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any gaps between dates will be treated as consecutive days.

```
with data as (
    select id, date,
        case when min(balance) >= 0 then 0 else 1 end as tally,
        sum(case when min(balance) >= 0 then 1 else 0 end)
            over (partition by id order by date) as grp
    from t
    group by id, date
)
select id, date,
    sum(tally) over (partition by id, grp, tally order by date) as running_days
from data
order by id, date;
```

To treat missing dates as nonconsecutive try:

```
    sum(case when min(balance) >= 0 then 1 else 0 end)
        over (partition by id order by date) +
    datediff(day, min(date) over (partition by id), date) -
    row_number() over (partition by id order by date) + 1 as grp
```

https://rextester.com/NKBZG48737

Answer (score 2):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem with filtering.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, dateadd(day, - seqnum, date)
                          order by date
                         ) as Number_of_Consecutive_Days
from (select t.id, date, min(balance) as min_balance,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.id, date
      having min(balance) < 0
     ) t;
```

This works by taking the days with negative balances only.  Then a sequential number is subtracted from the date.  For adjacent days, this is constant -- hence the difference in the outer `row_number()`.

EDIT:

If you just want to count the number of days with any negative balance up to a given date, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when min_balance < 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date) as Number_of_Consecutive_Days
from (select t.id, date, min(balance) as min_balance
      from t
      group by t.id, date
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think the EDIT: matches my logic more. However, it seems it does not work on my data for some reasons. I think it calculates all days with negative balance prior a date but I only need consecutive days with such criteria, not all days. Is there any other way to try? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Aliz . . . The first calculates consecutive days.  The second calculates overall days.  You can set up a db<>fiddle to validate this.